# How can I convert a function of input size defined recursively into a direct function of problem input size?

Tags: algorithm, math, time

Say I have an algorithm which operates on an input of size n and I know that the time it takes for n is twice the time it takes for n-1.  I can observe in this simple case (assuming it takes, say, 1 second for n = 0) that the algorithm takes 2<sup>n</sup> seconds.

Is there a general method for converting between recursively-defined definitions to the more familiar direct type of expression?

Comment: f(n) = 2**n instead of f(n) = 2*f(n-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Recursive functions" like this are called **Recurrence Relations**, and their "direct types" are known as the **Closed-form solution**.

While the Master Theorem listed by Poita is very helpful in computing time-complexity, it has nothing to do with actually solving recurrence relations.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving) and [Wolfram's Math World](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RecurrenceEquation.html) (under *"See Also"*) list the closed-forms of some common classes of recurrence relations.  However, complicated (non-linear) recurrence relations can be very difficult to find closed-form solutions to, if one exists at all.  There is no general algorithm for solving them.

Answer (score 8):

[Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem)

In particular:

With T(n) = aT(n/b) + n<sup>c</sup>

If log<sub>b</sub>a < c, then T(n) = O(n<sup>c</sup>)

If log<sub>b</sub>a = c, then T(n) = O(n<sup>c</sup>log[n])

If log<sub>b</sub>a > c, then T(n) = O(n<sup>log<sub>b</sub>a</sup>)

That's one useful theorem to know, but doesn't fully answer your question.

What you are looking for is the generator function of a recurrence relation. In general, these are only solvable for very simple cases, i.e. when f(n) = Af(n-1) + Bf(n-1) and f(0) = f(1) = 1 (or f(1) = A). Other recurrence relations are very difficult to solve.

See [linear recurrence relation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearRecurrenceEquation.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If it's linear, you can express the relation as a matrix and find the Eigen values, decomposing it into a form that lets you raise the eigen values to a power, as worked through for [Fibonacci here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525521/nth-fibonacci-number-in-sublinear-time/1526837#1526837).