# Test if a number is fibonacci

Tags: algorithm, testing, math, fibonacci

I know how to make the list of the Fibonacci numbers, but i don't know how can i test if a given number belongs to the fibonacci list - one way that comes in mind is generate the list of fib. numbers up to that number and see if it belongs to the array, but there's got to be another, simpler and faster method.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Looks like homework to me, so I added the homework tag.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525521/nth-fibonacci-number-in-sublinear-time for a related question.

Comment: Please allow the OP to add the homework tag on his own (feel free to ask for clarification).  Lots of things look like homework that aren't.

Comment: Please don't add tags just because it "looks like it would fit". It "looks to me" like the OP wants to do this in brainf*ck, should I add that tag?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432669

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test if a number is fibonacci](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432669/test-if-a-number-is-fibonacci)

Comment: This might help too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296664/code-chess-fibonacci-sequence/

Comment: See here for fast answers using only plus, minus and multiplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162780

Answer (score 92, accepted):

A very nice test is that N is a Fibonacci number if and only if `5 N^2 + 4` or `5N^2 – 4` is a square number.  For ideas on how to efficiently test that a number is square refer to the [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295579/fastest-way-to-determine-if-an-integers-square-root-is-an-integer).

Comment: +1 because saying "or" is more clear than saying "one of" + "and"  First 4 times I read the other answers I thought they were saying different things because I didn't see the "one of" part

Comment: I am skeptical of this solution, as it involves squaring a Fibonacci number.  Fibonacci numbers grow extremely quickly, and most are very large.  Doesn't squaring them become computationally expensive?

Comment: Well yeah, beyond 2^63 (something like Fib(300))  you're going to have to use some arbitrary precision arithmetic which will be expensive.  As the numbers grow, you must resort to approximate methods, either using Binet's formula or something else.  I would be surprised to learn any efficient exact method that works for large numbers!

Comment: Hm... If exactly one of the propositions A and B need to hold (but not both!), you cannot write "A or B", for this compound statement is true if A is true and B is false, if A is false and B is true, and if both A and B are true. Then you need to write explicitly "exactly one of", or use the logical "xor" operator rather than "or".

Comment: But it appears to be the case that "or" is indeed the correct operator. To see this, set N = 1. Then N is a Fibonacci number, and *both* 5*N^2 + 4 and 5*N^2 - 4 are perfect squares. If we had a xor operator, then "A xor B" would be false, even though 1 is Fibonacci, and we have a contradiction. (Here I assume that the theorem is correct with "or" or "xor".)

Comment: So I agree with Davy8: Saying like Wikipedia that "... a positive integer z is a Fibonacci number if and only if *one of* 5z^2 + 4 or 5z^2 − 4 is a perfect square." is actually incorrect. For the positive integer z=1, both numbers are perfect squares, i.e. two of them, and hence not one of them, so, the by the equivalence, 1 cannot be a Fibonacci number. But it is, and we have a contradiction.

Comment: Which of the two tests to use, you can decide by checking if `N` is _odd_ (`+4`) or _even_ (`-4`) [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100943/why-does-this-test-for-fibonacci-work)

Answer (score 54):

A positive integer ω is a Fibonacci number if and only if either 5ω<sup>2</sup> + 4 or 5ω<sup>2</sup> - 4 is a perfect square.

See [The Fabulous Fibonacci Numbers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1591024757) for more.

[image]

Answer (score 35):

While several people point out the perfect-square solution, it involves squaring a Fibonacci number, frequently resulting in a **massive** product.

There are less than 80 Fibonacci numbers that can even be held in a standard 64-bit integer.

Here is my solution, which operates entirely *smaller* than the number to be tested.
(written in C#, using basic types like `double` and `long`.  But the algorithm should work fine for bigger types.)

```
static bool IsFib(long T, out long idx)
{
    double root5 = Math.Sqrt(5);
    double phi = (1 + root5) / 2;

    idx    = (long)Math.Floor( Math.Log(T*root5) / Math.Log(phi) + 0.5 );
    long u = (long)Math.Floor( Math.Pow(phi, idx)/root5 + 0.5);

    return (u == T);
}
```

---

More than 4 years after I wrote this answer, a commenter asked about the second parameter, passed by `out`.

Parameter #2 is the "Index" into the Fibonacci sequence.
If the value to be tested, `T` is a Fibonacci number, then `idx` will be the 1-based index of that number in the Fibonacci sequence. (with one notable exception)

The Fibonacci sequence is `1 1 2 3 5 8 13`, etc. 
3  is the 4th number in the sequence: `IsFib(3, out idx);` will return `true` and value `4`.
8  is the 6th number in the sequence: `IsFib(8, out idx);` will return `true` and value `6`.
13 is the 7th number; `IsFib(13, out idx);` will return `true` and value `7`.

The one exception is `IsFib(1, out idx);`, which will return `2`, even though the value 1 appears at both index 1 and 2.

If `IsFib` is passed a non-Fibonacci number, it will return `false`, and the value of `idx` will be the index of the biggest Fibonacci number less than `T`.

16 is not a Fibonacci value.
`IsFib(16, out idx);` will return `false` and value `7`.
You can use [Binet's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Binets_formula) to convert index 7 into Fibonacci value 13, which is the largest number less than 16.

Comment: Concise implementation. I actually used this function in the contest: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/codesprint5/challenges/is-fibo :)

Comment: Thanks. It looks like magic. @Michal I have also used this function in hackerrank contest.

Comment: Very nice - thanks! I used it to get the closest Fibonacci number :) But in real life situation I think there is no need to compute these numbers, but store them in database (just like You suggest in Your other post)

Comment: just one question, what exactly is the second argument and why are you passing it by reference ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you come up with this?

Comment: This is just a straightforward use of the closed form, or Binet's Formula, solving for N, and testing the result.

All from the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

Answer (score 21):

```
#!/bin/bash
victim="144"
curl http://aux.planetmath.org/files/objects/7680/fib.txt | sed 's/^[0-9]*//;s/[ \t]//g' | grep "^$victim$" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ; then
    echo "$victim is a fibonacci number"
else
    echo "$victim aint"
fi
```

Comment: Outsourcing.  Love it!

Answer (score 12):

Positive integer ω is a Fibonacci number

> If and only if *one of*
>   5ω<sup>2</sup> + 4 and 5ω<sup>2</sup>
>   - 4 is a perfect square

from *The (Fabulous) FIBONACCI Numbers by Alfred Posamentier and Ingmar Lehmann*

```
bool isFibonacci(int  w)
{
       double X1 = 5 * Math.Pow(w, 2) + 4;
       double X2 = 5 * Math.Pow(w, 2) - 4;

       long X1_sqrt = (long)Math.Sqrt(X1);
       long X2_sqrt = (long)Math.Sqrt(X2);   

       return (X1_sqrt*X1_sqrt == X1) || (X2_sqrt*X2_sqrt == X2) ;
}
```

[**I copied it from this source**](http://www.interviewpattern.com/post/Fibonacci-numbers.aspx)

---

Snippet that prints Fibonacci numbers between `1k` and `10k`.

```
for (int i = 1000; i < 10000; i++)
{
         if (isFibonacci(i))
              Console.Write(" "+i);
}
```

**OMG There are only FOUR**!!!

With other method

```
from math import *

phi = 1.61803399
sqrt5 = sqrt(5)

def F(n):
    return int((phi**n - (1-phi)**n) /sqrt5)

def isFibonacci(z):
    return F(int(floor(log(sqrt5*z,phi)+0.5))) == z

print [i for i in range(1000,10000) if isFibonacci(i)]
```

Comment: No need for the "? true : false" part: the expression before that is already a boolean value.

Comment: I wrote second method in python because I didn't know C# Math.Log works for other bases as well. Do you guys want me to write it too :P?? lol

Answer (score 12):

If your numbers are of bounded size, than simply putting all fibonacci numbers below the upper bound into a hashtable and testing containment will do the trick. There are very few fibonacci numbers (for example, only 38 below 5mln), since they grow exponentially.

If your numbers are *not* of bounded size, then the suggested trick with square testing will almost surely be slower than generating the fibonacci sequence until the number is found or exceeded.

Comment: I'm skeptical of your last sentence. I programmed both approaches in Python and then timed them using the `timeit` module on a randomly chosen 1000 digit number. The square-based approach was 7 times faster.

Answer (score 11):

Towards a solution, take a look at Binet's Formula.
(Look for "Closed-Form Expression" under [Fibonacci Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) on Wikipedia)

It says that the sequence of Fibonacci Number's is created by a simple closed formula:

[image]

I believe if you solve for `n`, and test if `n` is an integer, you'll have your answer.

**Edit** As @psmears points out, the same Wikipedia article also has a section on detecting Fibonacci numbers.  Wikipedia is an excellent source.

Answer (score 9):

See the section "Recognizing Fibonacci numbers" on the [wikipedia article about the Fibonacci numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Recognizing_Fibonacci_numbers).

Comment: Hey, are you P Smears who was at Lincoln?

Answer (score 6):

Since Fibonacci numbers grow exponentially, the method you suggest is pretty fast.
Another is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Recognizing_Fibonacci_numbers).

Comment: I really like the closed interval solution, should be much easier than checking for squares!

Answer (score 3):

Based on earlier answers by me and psmears, I've written this C# code.

It goes through the steps slowly, and it can clearly be reduced and optimized:

```
// Input: T: number to test.
// Output: idx: index of the number in the Fibonacci sequence.
//    eg: idx for 8 is 6. (0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8)
// Return value: True if Fibonacci, False otherwise.
static bool IsFib(long T, out int idx)
{
    double root5 = Math.Sqrt(5);
    double PSI = (1 + root5) / 2;

    // For reference, IsFib(72723460248141) should show it is the 68th Fibonacci number

    double a;

    a = T*root5;
    a = Math.Log(a) / Math.Log(PSI);
    a += 0.5;
    a = Math.Floor(a);
    idx = (Int32)a;

    long u = (long)Math.Floor(Math.Pow(PSI, a)/root5 + 0.5);

    if (u == T)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        idx = 0;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Testing reveals this works for the first 69 Fibonacci numbers, but breaks down for the 70th.

```
F(69) = 117,669,030,460,994 - Works
F(70) = 190,392,490,709,135 - Fails
```

In all, unless you're using a BigInt library of some kind, it is probably better to have a simple lookup table of the Fibonacci Numbers and check that, rather than run an algorithm.

A list of the first 300 Numbers is readily available online.

But this code does outline a workable algorithm, provided you have enough precision, and don't overflow your number representation system.

Comment: The problem with phi is that it's not exactly usable using floating point numbers, and so you have to approximate.

Answer (score 2):

From Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

> A positive integer z is a Fibonacci
>   number if and only if one of 5z^2 + 4
>   or 5z^2 − 4 is a perfect square.

Comment: Weird. After 15 years of math, I did not know this.

Answer (score 2):

Re: Ahmad's code - a simpler approach with no recursion or pointers, fairly naive, but requires next to no computational power for anything short of really titanic numbers (roughly 2N additions to verify the Nth fib number, which on a modern machine will take milliseconds at worst)

// returns pos if it finds anything, 0 if it doesn't (C/C++ treats any value !=0 as true, so same end result)

```
int isFib (long n)
{
    int pos = 2;
    long last = 1;
    long current = 1;
    long temp;

    while (current < n)
    {
        temp = last;
        last = current;
        current = current + temp;
        pos++;
    }

    if (current == n)
        return pos;
    else
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: pretty sure this is the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: ` def is_fibonacci?(i)
  a,b=0,1
    until b >= i
        a,b=b,a+b
        return true if b == i
    end
end`

Answer (score 1):

The general expression for a Fibonacci number is
F(n) = [ [(1+sqrt(5))/2] sup n+1 - [(1-sqrt(5))/2] sup n+1 ]/ sqrt(5) ..... (*)
The second exponential goes to zero for large n and carrying out the
numerical operations we get F(n) = [ (1.618) sup n+1 ] / 2.236

If K is the number to be tested log(k*2.2336)/log(1.618) should be an integer!

Example for K equal to 13 my calculator gives the answer 7.00246
For K equal 14 the answer is 7.1564.

You can increase the confidence in the result by taking the closest integer to the
answer and substitute in (*) to confirm that the result is K

Answer (score 0):

How big are the numbers you're dealing with?

Could a lookup table work for you? (a precomputed list of numbers you can search in)

There's also a [closed-form expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) that I guess you could invert to get at the answer analytically (though I'm no mathematician, so I can't promise this suggestion makes sense)

Comment: I'm dealing with arbitrary numbers. Even an approximation will be useful, if it runs very quickly.

Comment: I think psmears has the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821778/im-looking-for-an-efficient-algorithm-to-test-whether-a-given-number-is-part-of/2821832#2821832

Answer (score 0):

I ran some benchmarks on the methods presented here along with simple addition, pre-computing an array, and memoizing the results in a hash.  For Perl, at least, the squaring method is a little bit faster than the logarithmic method, perhaps 20% faster.  As abelenky points out, it's a tradeoff between whether you've got the room for squaring bit numbers.

Certainly, the very fastest way is to hash all the Fibonacci numbers in your domain space.  Along the lines of another point that abelenky makes, there are only 94 of these suckers that are less than 2^64.

You should just pre-compute them, and put them in a Perl hash, Python dictionary, or whatever.

The properties of Fibonacci numbers are very interesting, but using them to determine whether some integer in a computer program is one is kind of like writing a subroutine to compute pi every time the program starts.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution I'm not sure if it benchmarks. I hope this helps!

```
def is_fibonacci?(i)
  a,b=0,1
    until b >= i
        a,b=b,a+b
        return true if b == i
    end
end
```

what **a,b=b,a+b** is doing

```
 0, 1 = 1, 0 +1
 1, 1 = 1, 1 + 1
 1, 2 = 2, 1 + 2
 2, 3 = 3, 2 + 3

fib1 = fib2
fib2 = fib1 + fib2
```

Answer (score 0):

A Scala version-

```
def isFib(n: Int): Boolean = {

def checkFib(f1: Int = 1, f2: Int = 1): Boolean = {

if(n == f1 || n == f2) true
else if(n < f2) false
else checkFib(f2, f1+f2)

}

checkFib()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java solution can be done as below. But still it can be optimized

The following solution works for

1. 1≤T≤10 ^5
2. 1≤N≤10 ^10

T is no.of test cases,
N is range of number

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.math.BigDecimal;
    import java.math.RoundingMode;

    public class FibonacciTester {
        private static BigDecimal zero = BigDecimal.valueOf(0);
        private static BigDecimal one = BigDecimal.valueOf(1);
        private static BigDecimal two = BigDecimal.valueOf(2);
        private static BigDecimal four = BigDecimal.valueOf(4);
        private static BigDecimal five = BigDecimal.valueOf(5);

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            BigDecimal[] inputs = new BigDecimal[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                inputs[i] = sc.nextBigDecimal();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                if (isFibonacci(inputs[i]))
                    System.out.println("IsFibo");
                else
                    System.out.println("IsNotFibo");
            }


        }

        public static boolean isFibonacci(BigDecimal num) {
            if (num.compareTo(zero) <= 0) {
                return false;
            }

            BigDecimal base = num.multiply(num).multiply(five);
            BigDecimal possibility1 = base.add(four);
            BigDecimal possibility2 = base.subtract(four);


            return (isPerfectSquare(possibility1) || isPerfectSquare(possibility2));
        }

        public static boolean isPerfectSquare(BigDecimal num) {
            BigDecimal squareRoot = one;
            BigDecimal square = one;
            BigDecimal i = one;
            BigDecimal newSquareRoot;
            int comparison = -1;

            while (comparison != 0) {
                if (comparison < 0) {
                    i = i.multiply(two);
                    newSquareRoot = squareRoot.add(i).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
                } else {
                    i = i.divide(two);
                    newSquareRoot = squareRoot.subtract(i).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
                }

                if (newSquareRoot.compareTo(squareRoot) == 0) {
                    return false;
                }

                squareRoot = newSquareRoot;
                square = squareRoot.multiply(squareRoot);
                comparison = square.compareTo(num);
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers are basically given. I would like to add a very fast C++ example code.

The basis is the lookup mechanism that has been mentioned here several times already.

With Binet's formula, we can calculate that there are only very few Fibonacci numbers that will fit in a C++ `unsigned long long` data type, which has usually 64 bit now in 2021. Roundabout 93. That is nowadays a really low number.

With modern C++ 17 (and above) features, we can easily create an `std::array` of all Fibonacci numbers for a 64bit data type at **compile time**.

So, we will spend only 93*8= 744 **BYTE** of none-runtime memory for our lookup array.

And then use `std::binary_search` for finding the value. So, the whole function will be:

```
bool isFib(const unsigned long long numberToBeChecked) {
    return std::binary_search(FIB.begin(), FIB.end(), numberToBeChecked);
}
```

FIB is a compile time, `constexpr std::array`. So, how to build that array?

We will first define the default approach for calculation a Fibonacci number as a `constexpr` function:

```
// Constexpr function to calculate the nth Fibonacci number
constexpr unsigned long long getFibonacciNumber(size_t index) noexcept {
    // Initialize first two even numbers 
    unsigned long long f1{ 0 }, f2{ 1 };

    // Calculating Fibonacci value 
    while (index--) {
        // get next value of Fibonacci sequence 
        unsigned long long f3 = f2 + f1;
        // Move to next number
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = f3;
    }
    return f2;
}
```

With that, Fibonacci numbers can easily be calculated at runtime. Then, we fill a `std::array` with all Fibonacci numbers. We use also a `constexpr` and make it a template with a variadic parameter pack.

We use `std::integer_sequence` to create a Fibonacci number for indices 0,1,2,3,4,5, ....

That is straigtforward and not complicated:

```
template <size_t... ManyIndices>
constexpr auto generateArrayHelper(std::integer_sequence<size_t, ManyIndices...>) noexcept {
    return std::array<unsigned long long, sizeof...(ManyIndices)>{ { getFibonacciNumber(ManyIndices)... } };
};
```

This function will be fed with an integer sequence 0,1,2,3,4,... and return a `std::array<unsigned long long, ...>` with the corresponding Fibonacci numbers.

We know that we can store maximum 93 values. And therefore we make a next function, that will call the above with the integer sequence 1,2,3,4,...,92,93, like so:

```
constexpr auto generateArray() noexcept {
    return generateArrayHelper(std::make_integer_sequence<size_t, MaxIndexFor64BitValue>());
}
```

And now, finally,

```
constexpr auto FIB = generateArray();
```

will give us a compile-time `std::array<unsigned long long, 93>` with the name FIB containing all Fibonacci numbers. And if we need the i'th Fibonacci number, then we can simply write `FIB[i]`. There will be no calculation at runtime.

---

The whole example program will look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// All the following will be done during compile time

// Constexpr function to calculate the nth Fibonacci number
constexpr unsigned long long getFibonacciNumber(size_t index) noexcept {
    // Initialize first two even numbers 
    unsigned long long f1{ 0 }, f2{ 1 };

    // calculating Fibonacci value 
    while (index--) {
        // get next value of Fibonacci sequence 
        unsigned long long f3 = f2 + f1;
        // Move to next number
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = f3;
    }
    return f2;
}
// We will automatically build an array of Fibonacci numbers at compile time
// Generate a std::array with n elements 
template <size_t... ManyIndices>
constexpr auto generateArrayHelper(std::integer_sequence<size_t, ManyIndices...>) noexcept {
    return std::array<unsigned long long, sizeof...(ManyIndices)>{ { getFibonacciNumber(ManyIndices)... } };
};

// Max index for Fibonaccis that for an 64bit unsigned value (Binet's formula)
constexpr size_t MaxIndexFor64BitValue = 93;

// Generate the required number of elements
constexpr auto generateArray()noexcept {
    return generateArrayHelper(std::make_integer_sequence<size_t, MaxIndexFor64BitValue>());
}

// This is an constexpr array of all Fibonacci numbers
constexpr auto FIB = generateArray();

// All the above was compile time
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------


// Check, if a number belongs to the Fibonacci series
bool isFib(const unsigned long long numberToBeChecked) {
    return std::binary_search(FIB.begin(), FIB.end(), numberToBeChecked);
}

// Test
int main() {

    const unsigned long long testValue{ 498454011879264ull };

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "Does '" <<testValue << "' belong to Fibonacci series?  --> " << isFib(498454011879264) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

---

Developed and tested with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.8.2

Additionally tested with gcc 10.2 and clang 11.0.1

Language: C++ 17

Answer (score -1):

```
int isfib(int n /* number */, int &pos /* position */)
{
   if (n == 1)
   {
      pos=2;  // 1 1
      return 1;
   }
   else if (n == 2)
   {
      pos=3;  // 1 1 2
      return 1;
   }
   else
   {
      int m = n /2;
      int p, q, x, y;
      int t1=0, t2 =0;
      for (int i = m; i < n; i++)
      {
        p = i;
        q = n -p;    // p + q = n
        t1 = isfib(p, x);
        if (t1) t2 = isfib(q, y);
        if (t1 && t2 && x == y +1)
        {
           pos = x+1;
           return 1; //true
        }
      }
      pos = -1;
      return 0; //false
   }
}
```

How about this?

Comment: good logic, but almost totally unreadable. gotta work on the variable naming

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
int number_entered, x, y;

printf("Please enter a number.\n");
scanf("%d", &number_entered);
x = y = 5 * number_entered^2 + 4;        /*Test if 5N^2 + 4 is a square number.*/
x = sqrt(x);
x = x^2;
if (x == y)
{
        printf("That number is in the Fibonacci sequence.\n");
    }
x = y = 5 * number_entered^2 - 4;        /*Test if 5N^2 - 4 is a square number.*/
x = sqrt(x);
x = x^2;
if (x == y)
{
    printf("That number is in the Fibonacci sequence.\n");
}
else
{
    printf("That number isn't in the Fibonacci sequence.\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Will this work?

Comment: No. In C, `^` is the *bitwise XOR* operator. You need `x * x` or `pow(x,2)` to square a number. There are also problems in the logic of the program.