# Python, return statement during backtracking

Tags: python, recursion

I was experimenting a little and something happened which I thought was not expected.
The question is based on recursion and the commented return statement on line
 7

```
def twentyone(nums, stack = [], answer = set()):
    for index, num in enumerate(nums):
        new_stack = stack + [num]
        total = sum(new_stack)
        if total == 21:
            answer.add(tuple(new_stack))
            #return
        elif total < 21:
            twentyone(nums[index + 1:], new_stack, answer)
    return answer

user_input = input()
list_format = [int(x) for x in user_input.split()]
answer = twentyone(list_format)

if len(answer) == 0:
    print("No combination of numbers add to 21")
for solution in answer:
    print("The values ", end = "")
    for number in solution:
            print("{} ".format(number), end = "")
    print("add up to 21")
```

My question is, during the test using the example input "1 9 11 5 6", if I have the return statement. The output is only "The values 1 9 11 add up to 21", but without the return statement the output is "The values 1 9 11 add up to 21
The values 1 9 5 6 add up to 21".
I was wondering if anything could explain why, I thought that the return statement would simply "speed up" ending this recursive instance of the method instead of simply skipping over the other lines of code which it wont reach and since I have already added the tuple to the mutable set, it would have been added in other recursive instances and thus no problem. But I was of course wrong.

Comment: You need to be very careful when using mutable objects as default arguments: they may not do what you want. Please see [“Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) for details.

Comment: Please let me know if there's anything in my answer that you need explained further.

Answer (score 2):

That `return` statement causes the `for` loop to terminate prematurely, so it may not find all possible solutions at that particular recursion depth.

We can see this by adding an extra list to the function that tracks the `for` loop indices. Note that I give `indices` a default value of `None` - that's the standard way of avoiding the default mutable argument pitfall.

```
def twentyone(nums, stack = [], answer = set(), indices = None):
    if indices is None:
        indices = []
    for index, num in enumerate(nums):
        new_stack = stack + [num]
        total = sum(new_stack)
        if total == 21:
            print(indices + [index], new_stack)
            answer.add(tuple(new_stack))
            #return
        elif total < 21:
            twentyone(nums[index + 1:], new_stack, answer, indices + [index])

    return answer

user_input = '1 9 11 5 6 3 7'
list_format = [int(x) for x in user_input.split()]
answer = twentyone(list_format)
print('\n', answer)
```

**output**

```
[0, 0, 0] [1, 9, 11]
[0, 0, 1, 0] [1, 9, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 1, 0] [1, 11, 6, 3]
[1, 1, 2] [9, 5, 7]
[2, 2, 0] [11, 3, 7]
[3, 0, 0, 0] [5, 6, 3, 7]

 {(9, 5, 7), (1, 11, 6, 3), (1, 9, 5, 6), (1, 9, 11), (5, 6, 3, 7), (11, 3, 7)}
```

If we un-comment the `return`, we get this output:

```
[0, 0, 0] [1, 9, 11]
[0, 1, 1, 0] [1, 11, 6, 3]
[1, 1, 2] [9, 5, 7]
[2, 2, 0] [11, 3, 7]
[3, 0, 0, 0] [5, 6, 3, 7]

 {(9, 5, 7), (5, 6, 3, 7), (1, 11, 6, 3), (1, 9, 11), (11, 3, 7)}
```

`[0, 0, 1, 0]` is missing from the indices, which means that the `for` loop of `[0, 0, 0]` was terminated prematurely.

---

As I mentioned earlier, it can be dangerous to use mutable objects for default arguments. This is discussed extensively at [“Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

In this code you don't get a problem because you only have one call of `twentyone` that uses the default args and the recursive call supplies explicit args. But if your calling code called `twentyone` a second time with another list of user input, then the default `answer` will still have the items it collected during the previous call. The `stack` list is safe since you never mutate it.

Note that the behaviour of default mutable arguments isn't always a pitfall. It's extremely useful for implementing caching; see my answer to [Fibonacci in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683466/4014959) for an example.

---

FWIW, here's a version of `twentyone` that doesn't have the default mutable argument problem. I've also changed `stack` & `new_stack` into tuples. That saves the `tuple` call; creating a new tuple with `new_stack = stack + (num,)` is no less efficient than creating a new list with `new_stack = stack + [num]`. Tuples are slightly more efficient than lists, and there's not much point in using lists for `stack` / `new_stack` since they never get mutated.

```
def twentyone(nums, stack=(), answer=None):
    if answer is None:
        answer = set()
    for index, num in enumerate(nums):
        new_stack = stack + (num,)
        total = sum(new_stack)
        if total == 21:
            answer.add(new_stack)
        elif total < 21:
            twentyone(nums[index + 1:], new_stack, answer)

    return answer
```

---

Another way to implement this is as a recursive generator. That way we don't need `answer`, we just yield solutions as we find them.

```
def twentyone(nums, stack=()):
    for index, num in enumerate(nums):
        new_stack = stack + (num,)
        total = sum(new_stack)
        if total == 21:
            yield new_stack
        elif total < 21:
            yield from twentyone(nums[index + 1:], new_stack)

user_input = '1 9 11 5 6 3 7'
list_format = [int(x) for x in user_input.split()]
for t in twentyone(list_format):
    print(t)
```

**output**

```
(1, 9, 11)
(1, 9, 5, 6)
(1, 11, 6, 3)
(9, 5, 7)
(11, 3, 7)
(5, 6, 3, 7)
```

The downside of this is that if there are duplicate items in `nums` then we get duplicate solutions. But we can easily get around that by running the generator inside `set()`:

```
print(set(twentyone(list_format)))
```

**output**

```
{(9, 5, 7), (1, 11, 6, 3), (1, 9, 5, 6), (1, 9, 11), (5, 6, 3, 7), (11, 3, 7)}
```

However, this only eliminates exact duplicates, it doesn't get rid of solutions that are permutations of previous solutions. To make it totally foolproof, we need to sort the output tuples.

```
def twentyone(nums, stack=()):
    for index, num in enumerate(nums):
        new_stack = stack + (num,)
        total = sum(new_stack)
        if total == 21:
            yield tuple(sorted(new_stack))
        elif total < 21:
            yield from twentyone(nums[index + 1:], new_stack)

user_input = '1 9 5 11 5 6 5'
list_format = [int(x) for x in user_input.split()]
print(set(twentyone(list_format)))
```

**output**

```
{(1, 9, 11), (1, 5, 6, 9), (5, 5, 11), (5, 5, 5, 6)}
```