# Find the fibonacci sum that is less than a given number in less than O(n)

Tags: python, algorithm, lambda, functional-programming

I am trying to work on a problem and part of the solution is to find the sum of finbonacci numbers that is less than an input number. Now the upper limit of the input number is 10**9. I have reduced the problem to the following O(n) solution, I was wondering if there is a more efficient solution.

```
b=[1, 2, 4, 7, 12, 20, 33, 54, 88, 143, 232, 376, 609, 986, 1596, 2583, 4180, 6764, 
10945, 17710, 28656, 46367, 75024, 121392, 196417, 317810, 514228, 832039, 
1346268, 2178308, 3524577, 5702886, 9227464, 14930351, 24157816, 
39088168, 63245985, 102334154, 165580140, 267914295, 433494436, 701408732, 1134903169, 1836311902]

def test_lambda(a):
    list_numbers= filter(lambda x: x<=a, b)
    return len(list_numbers)
```

As you can see I am comparing the values of the list b with the given input and returning the elements that are less than the given number.

b is the list of sum of fibonaccis numbers upto that index, so the 1st number is 1, the sum is 1, the 2nd is 1 the sum is 2, the 3rd 2 the sum 4...

Comment: Do you know there is a solution of less than O(n), or you just want one?

Comment: Simply use binary search...

Comment: I don't know if there is a solution that is less than O(n)...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Binary search on what?

Comment: I have considered binary search but the input does not necessarily have to be in the list. So the binary search will return -1.. atleast from what I know..

Comment: @fazkan The only thing I can think of is to use the formula for the n'th element: https://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/10002.4-5.shtml

Comment: Ah.. I've misread the question. You have a precalculated list. Then yes, use the binary search...

Comment: @EugeneSh. yea i have used that, you are talking about the binets formula. its an approximation and it fails for large numbers...

Comment: @EugeneSh.: well the list is a running sum, so it is ordered. And we actually want to know the number of sums before the "virtual" insertion point `a`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yeah, I have missed the fact the list is already precalculated.

Comment: The sum of the first n Fibonacci numbers is fib(n+2)-1. As for efficiently finding the nearest Fibonacci number to a given number, please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683466/4014959

Comment: [@PM2Ring: you *did* notice the literals in array `b`, didn't you?]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use *binary search* (for instance using the [`bisect_right`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_right) function) for that:

```
from bisect import bisect_right

def test_lambda(a):
    return bisect_right(list_numbers,a)
```

Or if you want the sum that is less than the input number, you can use:

```
from bisect import bisect_right

def less_than(a):
    return a[bisect_right(list_numbers,a)-1]
```

This works since the list is pre-calculated and is strictly incrementing. So that means that it is an ordered list. Binary search works in *O(log n)* so searching is done efficiently. Furthermore I would add `0` to the list (at the first position), such that queries with `0` as input are resolved as well:

```
from bisect import bisect_right

b=[0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 12, 20, 33, 54, 88, 143, 232, 376, 609, 986, 1596, 2583, 
   4180, 6764, 10945, 17710, 28656, 46367, 75024, 121392, 196417, 317810,
   514228, 832039, 1346268, 2178308, 3524577, 5702886, 9227464, 14930351,
   24157816, 39088168, 63245985, 102334154, 165580140, 267914295, 433494436,
   701408732, 1134903169, 1836311902
  ]

def less_than(a):
    return a[bisect_right(list_numbers,a)-1]
```

Comment: @fazkan: it is definitely *O(log n)* for searching (definitely given the elements are all different), as is documented in the `insort_left` function.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in O(logn)*O(logn) using matrix exponentiation please refer to the link below 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102452/modulus-of-sum-of-sequence-of-fibonacci-numbers 
incase you don't have enough memory to store all 10^9 sums you can use this O(logn) to calculate the i'th sum, if you want the sum less than equal to the given input you can just binary search for i