# i want to get the next fibonacci number

Tags: python-3.x, fibonacci

I want to find the next fibonacci number in the fibonacci series. Like if i entered 9 then the function should return 13 which is next fibonacci number.

i could not understood logic how it can be implemented. Just messing with fibonacci program.

```py
def Fibonacci(n): 
    if n<0:
        print("Incorrect input") 
    elif n==1:
        return 0
    elif n==2:
        return 1
    else: 
        return Fibonacci(n-1)+Fibonacci(n-2) 

print(Fibonacci(9)) 

if i entered 9 then the function should return 13 which is next fibonacci number.
```

Comment: The code you have prints the n-th Fibonacci number, not "the closest Fibonacci number that is larger than n"

Comment: this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682947/how-to-find-the-nearest-fibonacci-series-number (or even a duplicate?).

Comment: @hiroprotagonist isn't that an exact duplicate?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist looking forward to it.

Comment: @DeepSpace almost... if i understand correctly this will give the closest fibonacci number; not necessarily the next one (but that should be easy). i still flagged the question as a duplicate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the number 'n'.
In your program you ask for the n'th number which is not equal to for instance the number 9.
So your program will work if you want to calculate the n'th fibonacci number.
To get what you want you would have to do something like:

```
    def Fibonnacci(givenNumber):
        number1 = 1
        number2 = 1
        nextFibo = number1 + number2
        while nextFibo <= givenNumber:
            number1 = number2
            number2 = nextFibo
            nextFibo = number1 + number2

        return nextFibo

    print(Fibonnacci(9))
```