# get Fibonacci number index, recursively

Tags: recursion, fibonacci

I need a **recursive function** which can get me the index of a Fibonacci number passed to it.

For example, the mentioned function should return 6 when we pass 8; or it should return 8 when we pass 21.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks !

Comment: Yeah, what have you tried?

Comment: while that is certainly true, it's a very interesting problem

Comment: Thanks for your guidance ! I will update the question soon.

Comment: Very well, I'll keep an eye on it. Good luck, I'm looking forward to see the improvements! Also, if you find the answer yourself, it _is_ OK to post your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my solution ! 
It works fine and return what I expect. 
Make sure that **a** and **b** have their own default value in function declaration.

```
int getTermIndex(int, int&, int=1, int=1);
```

***function implementation:***

```
int getTermIndex(int number, int& i, int a, int b) {

    if(number==0) return i;
    else if(number==1){
        i++;
        return i;
    }

    int nextFib = a+b;

    if(nextFib==number || nextFib>number) {
        i += 3;
        return i;
    }
    else {
        i++;
        getTermIndex(number, i, b, nextFib);
    }

}
```

***function usage:***

```
int number;
cin >> number;

int nth=0;
getTermIndex(number, nth);
```

Comment: Well done! I've retracted my vote-to-close. If you're interested in further reading, there is a (non-recursive)  version [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5162780/812149).

Comment: though syntactically recursive, semantically this is an iterative procedure. Indeed in languages with tail-call optimization is *is* just a loop. Your code even depends on this, as there's no `return` statement in the final `else` clause.