# How to check if a number is a fibonacci number?

Tags: scala

Im trying to create a function that determines if a number is a fibonacci number or not in Scala. Can someone look at my code and let me know what I'm missing? Thanks

```
def isFibNumber(n: Int): Boolean = {

  var fib1 = 0;
  var  fib2 = 1;
do {
    var saveFib1 = fib1;
    fib1 = fib2;
    fib2 = saveFib1 + fib2;
    }
while (fib2 < n);

if (fib2 == n)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: For alternative solutions see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432669/test-if-a-number-is-fibonacci

Comment: @ Thilo thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would help. No loop required

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-number-fibonacci-number/

```
object Fib {


  def isPerfectSq(n: Int): Boolean = {
    val res = math.round(math.sqrt(n))
    res * res == n.toLong
  }

  def isFibonacci(n: Int) = {
    isPerfectSq(5 * n * n - 4) || isPerfectSq(5 * n * n + 4)
  }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Hmmm... is it getting in some strange overflow issues? `isFibonacci(fib(29))` returns false. Same for others higher. I feel it hits an Int limitation right around there.

Comment: Perhaps you might want to use Long, or even BigInt

Answer (score 2):

```
def isFibonacciNumber(n: Int): Boolean = {
  var fib1 = -1;
  var  fib2 = 1;
  var res = 0;

do {
    res = fib1+fib2;
    fib1 = fib2;
    fib2 = res;
} while (res < n);

if (res == n)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}
```

This should work. You had error in your algorithm.

Comment: Did you test your code? it doesnt seem to be working. Also as part of the requeriment of this task I need to use def isFibNumber(n: Int): Boolean = {     and not def firstNFibonacciNumbers(n: Int): Stream[Int] = {

Comment: @abpre can u be more presice? So I can help you.