# The number of Fibonacci numbers lesser than a given n

Tags: c, count, fibonacci

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fibonacci(int n) {
    int count, n1 = 0, n2 = 1, fib = 0;
    printf("Given number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    count = 0;
    while (count < n) {
        fib = n1 + n2;
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = fib;
        ++count;
        if (n > fib)
            printf("%d ", fib);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int szam;
    fibonacci(szam);
    return 0;
}
```

I've gotten this far, I just don't know how to count the numbers.
for example:

input: `10`

output: `1 2 3 5 8`

but it should be:

in: `10`

out: `5`

Comment: Your title is wrong. Did you mean number of fibonacci numbers lesser than N?

Comment: Maybe print `count` after the loop, and don't print `fib` inside the loop?

Comment: Hint: Fibonacci numbers grow very fast. Use it if range of N is bounded.

Comment: if i print count after the loop, i just get the given number

Comment: @TamásSándor each time you `printf()` in the loop, your count of the number of numbers goes up.... so increment a new counter instead of calling `printf()` there (and call `printf()` to display that new counter afterwards)

Comment: @mah it works, thanks!

Comment: @TamásSándor: can you please click on the grey check mark below the score of the answer that you wish to accept.

Comment: I think this function will help you figure this out extremely quickly:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432669/test-if-a-number-is-fibonacci/2822801#2822801

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stop condition in your code is incorrect: you stop after `n` fibonacci numbers have been computed instead of stopping when you have computed a fibonacci number larger than `n`.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int count_fibonacci(unsigned long long int n) {
    int count = 0;
    unsigned long long n1 = 1, n2 = 1, fib = 1;
    while (fib < n) {
        count++;
        fib = n1 + n2;
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = fib;
    }
    return count;
}

int main(void) {
    unsigned long long n = 0;
    printf("Given number: ");
    scanf("%llu", &n);
    printf("%d\n", count_fibonacci(n));
    return 0;
}
```

It prints `5` for an input of `10`, because your fibonacci sequence is: `1 2 3 5 8...`.

But the standard sequence is usually defined as `1 1 2 3 5 8...`, and it should return `6`.  You can get this behavior bu changing the initial state to `n1 = 0, n2 = 1, fib = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Added the variable *fib_count* that counts the Fibonacci numbers (did not test this...)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fibonacci(int n)
{
  int n1=0, n2=1, fib=0, fib_count;
  printf("Given number: ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  fib_count = 0;
  while (fib<n)
  {`

      fib=n1+n2;
      n1=n2;
      n2=fib;
      fib_count += 1;
      printf("%d ",fib);

  }
  printf("Fibonacci numbers smaller than %d : %d ",n, fib_count);
  return 0;
}

int main(){
int szam;
fibonacci(szam);
return 0;
}
```