# Wrong results for fibonacci-test (C++)

Tags: c++

I started to learn C++ and my homework is to write a code where you can enter 5 numbers and the program will tell you for each number whether it is a Fibonacci number or not.

I also tried using a do/while-loop in the isFibonacci function instead of the for-loop, but that did not fix the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

//function to test whether a number is a Fibonacci number or not
bool isFibonacci (int i) 
{
    //special cases with 0 and 1:
    if ( i == 0 || i ==1) {
        return true;  
    } 
    //for all other numbers:
    int Fib1;
    int Fib2;
    int Fib3;
    for (Fib3=0; Fib3>=i; Fib3++) {
        Fib3 = Fib1 + Fib2;
        Fib1 = Fib2;
        Fib2 = Fib3;
        if (Fib3==i){
            return true;
        } 
        else {
            return false;
        } 
    }
} 

int main () 
{
    bool result;
    int numbers[5]; 
    int i;
    //asking for the 5 numbers
    cout << "Please enter 5 numbers;" << endl;
    cin >> numbers[0] >> numbers[1] >> numbers[2] >> numbers[3] >> numbers[4];

    // giving back the result
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        result=isFibonacci (numbers[i]);
        if (result == true) {
            cout << "Your number " << numbers[i] << " is a Fibonacci  number!" << endl;
        } 
        else {
            cout << "Your number " << numbers[i] << " is not a Fibonacci number!" << endl;
        } 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

The first Fibonacci numbers are (0),1,1,2,3,5,8,12.
So when I enter 5 numbers, for example 1,2,3,4,5 I should get a "yes" for 1,2,3 and 5, but a "no" for 4.
However, my program claims that except for 1, none of these numbers are Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: `Fib3 = Fib1 + Fib2;` - this is bogus since you never initialized your variables.

Comment: variables must be initialised. Also your conditions in the loop are not adequate, because `Fib3` is still modified in the loop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your approach was a good idea. But you made some implementation errors in your check function. Like not initialized variables and wrong calculations. And look at you for loop.

Additionally. There will be a problem with big numbers.

Many very smart people, explored the Fibonacci numbers. There are whole books available. Also a Wikipedia article. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

Or look into that book:

[The(Fabulous) FIBONACCI Numbers by Alfred Posamentierand Ingmar Lehmann](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1591024757)

Or also here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432669/test-if-a-number-is-fibonacci)

Therefore I will not reinvent the wheel. Here is your revised software:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <numeric>


// Positive integer ? is a Fibonacci number
// If and only if one of 5?2 + 4 and 5?2 - 4 is a perfect square
// from The(Fabulous) FIBONACCI Numbers by Alfred Posamentierand Ingmar Lehmann
// Function to test whether a number is a Fibonacci number or not
bool isFibonacci(int w)
{
    {
        double x1 = 5 * std::pow(w, 2) + 4;
        double x2 = 5 * std::pow(w, 2) - 4;

        long x1_sqrt = static_cast<long>(std::sqrt(x1));
        long x2_sqrt = static_cast<long>(std::sqrt(x2));

        return (x1_sqrt * x1_sqrt == x1) || (x2_sqrt * x2_sqrt == x2);
    }
}

int main()
{
    bool result;
    int numbers[5];
    int i;
    //asking for the 5 numbers
    std::cout << "Please enter 5 numbers;" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> numbers[0] >> numbers[1] >> numbers[2] >> numbers[3] >> numbers[4];

    // giving back the result
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        result = isFibonacci(numbers[i]);
        if (result == true) {
            std::cout << "Your number " << numbers[i] << " is a Fibonacci  number!" << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Your number " << numbers[i] << " is not a Fibonacci number!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In case anyone is interested in the math, the reason this "works" is because of implicit properties of the [fibonacci sequence closed form](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/a-closed-form-of-the-fibonacci-sequence). If you haven't hit deriving these formulas from linear recurrence sequences in your math studies yet, prepare to enjoy it because its one of the more fun periods of collegiate math.

Comment: That helps a lot, thank you very much! I just started and still have a lot to learn