# Issue finding last digits of the nth term in the Fibonacci sequence

Tags: c, fibonacci, modulus

I wrote some code to determine the nth Fibonacci number using the nice blog post given in the accepted answer to this question: [Finding out nth fibonacci number for very large 'n'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661633/finding-out-nth-fibonacci-number-for-very-large-n). I am doing this as a way of practising a more difficult recursion problem given on projecteuler but that is not really relevant. The method relies on changing the problem to a small linear algebra problem of the form

Fn = T^n F1

where F1 = (1 1)^t and Fn contains the nth and (n-1)th Fibonacci number. The term T^n can then be determined in O(log n) time. I implemented this succesfully and it seems to work fine. When I perform the matrix exponentiation I use %10000 so I get the last 4 digits only, which seems to work (I checked against some large Fibonacci numbers). However, I wanted to try to get more last digits by increasing the number 10000. This doesn't seem to work however. I no longer get the correct answer. Here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

const unsigned long M = 10000;

unsigned long int * matProd(unsigned long int * A, unsigned long int * B){
  unsigned long int * C;
  C = malloc(4*sizeof(unsigned long int));
  C[0] = ((A[0]*B[0]%M) + (A[1]*B[2]%M)) % M;
  C[1] = ((A[0]*B[1]%M) + (A[1]*B[3]%M)) % M;
  C[2] = ((A[2]*B[0]%M) + (A[3]*B[2]%M)) % M;
  C[3] = ((A[2]*B[1]%M) + (A[3]*B[3]%M)) % M;
  return C;
}

unsigned long int * matExp(unsigned long int *A, unsigned long int n){
  if (n==1){
    return A;
  }
  if (n%2==0){
    return matExp(matProd(A,A),n/2);
  }
  return matProd(A,matExp(A,n-1));
}

unsigned long int findFib(unsigned long int n){
  unsigned long int A[4] = {0, 1, 1, 1};
  unsigned long int * C;
  C = malloc(4*sizeof(unsigned long int));
  C = matExp(A,n-2);
  return (C[2]+C[3]);
}

main(){
  unsigned long int n = 300;
  printf("%ld\n",findFib(n));
}
```

There are probably several issues there with regards to proper coding conventions and things that can be improved. I thought changing to long int might solve the problem but this does not seem to do the trick. So basically the problem is that increasing M to for instance 1000000 does not give me more digits but instead gives me nonsense. What mistake am I making?

P.S. sorry for the poor math formatting, I am used to math.stackexchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably that you are running on a system where `long` is 32-bits in size, as I believe is the case for Windows. You can check this by compiling and running `printf("%d\n", sizeof(long))` which should output `4`.

Since with `M=1000000=10^6`, the product of two numbers smaller than `M` can go up to `10^12`, you get overflow issues when you are computing your matrix entries since `unsigned long` can hold up to at most `2^32-1` or roughly `4 * 10^9`.

To fix this simply using `unsigned long long` as your type instead of `unsigned long`. Or better yet, `uint64_t`, which is guaranteed to be 64-bits in all platforms (and which will require `#include <stdint.h>`). This should make your code work for `M` up to `sqrt(2^64)~10^9`. If you need bigger than that you'll need to use a big integer library.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this indeed works. I was considering perhaps defining my own recursive function for multiplying two numbers which finds a*b by adding b to itself a times, each time performing the modulo operation. This will be horridly slow probably but should alleviate the problems with overflow. Anyway, thanks for the  helpful answer!

Comment: Unclear as why `uint64_t` is _better_ than `unsigned long long` here.  `unsigned long long` is at least 64-bit and `uint64_t` need not exist (albeit on rare machines) to be compliant.  If anything, code could use `uint_least64_t`.

Answer (score 1):

If the program works for `M == 10000` but fails for `M == 1000000` (or even for `M == 100000`) then that probably means that your C implementation's `unsigned long int` type is 32 bits wide.

If your matrix elements are drawn exclusively from Z<sup>10000</sup>, then they require at most 14 significant binary digits.  The products you compute in your matrix multiplication function, before reducing modulo `M`, may therefore require up to 28 binary digits.  If you increase `M` even to 100000, however, then the matrix elements require up to 17 binary digits, and the intermediate products require up to 34.  The reduction modulo `M` is too late to prevent that overflowing a 32-bit integer and therefore giving you garbage results.

You could consider declaring the element type as `uint64_t` instead.  If it's an overflow problem then that should give you enough extra digits to handle `M == 1000000`.