# Find The Millionth Fibonacci in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, fibonacci

In Fibonacci sequence each item is the sum of the previous two.

```
fibonacci(1) == 1, fibonacci(0) == 0; 
fibonacci(2) = fibonacci(1) + fibonacci(0);
...
```

After searching the web I find this algorithm to solve:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And here is my code:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Fibonacci {
    public static BigInteger fib(BigInteger n) {
        double p = (1 + Math.sqrt(5)) / 2;
        double q = (1 - Math.sqrt(5) / 2;
        BigInteger result = BigInteger.ZERO;
        result = ( Math.pow(p, n) - Math.pow(q, n) ) / Math.sqrt(5); //error
        return result;
    }
}
```

How to solve that error, **I want the parameter is BigInteger, not Integer**, and the return number is BigInteger, too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding out nth fibonacci number for very large 'n'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661633/finding-out-nth-fibonacci-number-for-very-large-n)

Comment: No duplicate, please consider again from my question.

Comment: `How to solve that error` - which _that_ error? How about sidestepping? What are you trying to achieve in the first place?

Comment: error in my code, Math.pow(parameter 1, parameter 2) <-- this return double value. I want it to return BigInteger value.

Comment: I am curious where you found that formula for the Fibonacci sequence. I have never seen it expressed like that. Do you have a link?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `Math.pow()` you need to use [BigDecimal#pow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#pow(int)).

Because `Math.pow()` returns `double`, but if `p` and `n` are too large then it will raise primitive overflow error.

```
BigDecimal bp = new BigDecimal(p);
BigDecimal bq = new BigDecimal(q);

BigDecimal result = bp.pow(n); // n must be in the range 0 through 999999999, inclusive. ZERO.
```

Now `result` got `p^n` as `BigDecimal`. Hope you understand the `BigDecimal` calculation.

Comment: Is this: BigInteger.ZERO.pow(n)?
But how to put the p and q in it?

Comment: I write some code for you, let me know if that helps you or not.

Comment: BigDecimal result = bp.pow(n); //error with n, because n is BigInteger

Comment: Because the method `pow(int exponent)` take param as `int`.

Comment: I know, but I need the parameter in my function is BigInteger, how to do with it?

Comment: Unfortunately JAVA currently don't support _exponent_ as `BigDecimal`

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help. Maybe I will find the other way.

Answer (score 1):

The standard mathematical operators in Java is not overridden for `Big` numbers. These are just objects. So you have to work with them as objects.

```
public static BigInteger fib(int n) {
    BigDecimal phi = new BigDecimal((1 + Math.sqrt(5)) / 2).pow(n);
    BigDecimal phi_ = new BigDecimal((1 - Math.sqrt(5)) / 2).pow(n);
    BigDecimal divider = new BigDecimal(Math.sqrt(5));
    BigDecimal result = phi.subtract(phi_).divide(divider);
    return result.toBigInteger();
}
```

**Updated:**

As @Gassa said, the above method accumulates error because

> `BigDecimal` is initialized by a `double` which in turn has precision of
>   only 15 decimal digits

but we need much more.

So we can use sqrt method for `BigDecimal` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17306433/2450152):

```
public static BigInteger fib(int n) {
    BigDecimal one = new BigDecimal(1);
    BigDecimal sqrtFive = bigSqrt(new BigDecimal(5));
    BigDecimal two = new BigDecimal(2);

    BigDecimal phi = one.add(sqrtFive).divide(two, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN).pow(n);
    BigDecimal phi_ = one.subtract(sqrtFive).divide(two, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN).pow(n);

    BigDecimal result = phi.subtract(phi_).divide(sqrtFive, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);

    return result.toBigInteger();
}

private static final BigDecimal SQRT_DIG = new BigDecimal(150);
private static final BigDecimal SQRT_PRE = new BigDecimal(10).pow(SQRT_DIG.intValue());

/**
 * Private utility method used to compute the square root of a BigDecimal.
 *
 * @author Luciano Culacciatti
 * @url http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/257031/Implementing-SqrtRoot-in-BigDecimal
 */
private static BigDecimal sqrtNewtonRaphson  (BigDecimal c, BigDecimal xn, BigDecimal precision){
    BigDecimal fx = xn.pow(2).add(c.negate());
    BigDecimal fpx = xn.multiply(new BigDecimal(2));
    BigDecimal xn1 = fx.divide(fpx,2*SQRT_DIG.intValue(), RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
    xn1 = xn.add(xn1.negate());
    BigDecimal currentSquare = xn1.pow(2);
    BigDecimal currentPrecision = currentSquare.subtract(c);
    currentPrecision = currentPrecision.abs();
    if (currentPrecision.compareTo(precision) <= -1){
        return xn1;
    }
    return sqrtNewtonRaphson(c, xn1, precision);
}

/**
 * Uses Newton Raphson to compute the square root of a BigDecimal.
 *
 * @author Luciano Culacciatti
 * @url http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/257031/Implementing-SqrtRoot-in-BigDecimal
 */
public static BigDecimal bigSqrt(BigDecimal c){
    return sqrtNewtonRaphson(c,new BigDecimal(1),new BigDecimal(1).divide(SQRT_PRE));
}
```

Comment: @Gassa, thanks a lot, I really forgot about the accuracy of `double`. I updated my answer.