# How to implement a Spliterator for streaming Fibonacci numbers?

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing, java-8, spliterator

I'm playing with Java 8 [Spliterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html) and created one to stream Fibonacci numbers up to a given n. So for the Fibonacci series `0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, ...`

```
n    fib(n)
-----------
-1   0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    2
```

Following is my implementation which prints a bunch of 1 before running out of stack memory. Can you help me find the bug? (I think it's not advancing the `currentIndex` but I'm not sure what value to set it to).

**Edit 1**: If you decide to answer, please keep it relevant to the question. This question is not about efficient fibonacci number generation; it's about learning spliterators.

FibonacciSpliterator:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FibonacciSpliterator implements Spliterator<FibonacciPair> {
    private int currentIndex = 3;
    private FibonacciPair pair = new FibonacciPair(0, 1);

    private final int n;

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super FibonacciPair> action) {
//        System.out.println("tryAdvance called.");
//        System.out.printf("tryAdvance: currentIndex = %d, n = %d, pair = %s.\n", currentIndex, n, pair);

        action.accept(pair);

        return n - currentIndex >= 2;
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<FibonacciPair> trySplit() {
//        System.out.println("trySplit called.");

        FibonacciSpliterator fibonacciSpliterator = null;

        if (n - currentIndex >= 2) {
//            System.out.printf("trySplit Begin: currentIndex = %d, n = %d, pair = %s.\n", currentIndex, n, pair);

            fibonacciSpliterator = new FibonacciSpliterator(n);

            long currentFib = pair.getMinusTwo() + pair.getMinusOne();
            long nextFib = pair.getMinusOne() + currentFib;

            fibonacciSpliterator.pair = new FibonacciPair(currentFib, nextFib);
            fibonacciSpliterator.currentIndex = currentIndex + 3;

//            System.out.printf("trySplit End: currentIndex = %d, n = %d, pair = %s.\n", currentIndex, n, pair);
        }

        return fibonacciSpliterator;
    }

    @Override
    public long estimateSize() {
        return n - currentIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public int characteristics() {
        return ORDERED | IMMUTABLE | NONNULL;
    }
}
```

FibonacciPair:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Value
public class FibonacciPair {
    private final long minusOne;
    private final long minusTwo;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%d %d ", minusOne, minusTwo);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Spliterator<FibonacciPair> spliterator = new FibonacciSpliterator(5);

StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, true)
    .forEachOrdered(System.out::print);
```

Comment: This code does not compile - please post the correct code.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon, what's the compilation error you're having? The code uses Lombok so you'll need that to make sense of the annotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, let's write the spliterator. Using `OfLong` is still too boring: let's switch to `BigInteger` and don't limit user by 92. The tricky thing here is to quickly jump to the given Fibonacci number. I'll use matrix multiplication algorithm described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14662102/4856258) for this purpose. Here's my code:

```
static class FiboSpliterator implements Spliterator<BigInteger> {
    private final static BigInteger[] STARTING_MATRIX = {
        BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ONE, 
        BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ZERO};

    private BigInteger[] state; // previous and current numbers
    private int cur; // position
    private final int fence; // max number to cover by this spliterator

    public FiboSpliterator(int max) {
        this(0, max);
    }

    // State is not initialized until traversal
    private FiboSpliterator(int cur, int fence) {
        assert fence >= 0;
        this.cur = cur;
        this.fence = fence;
    }

    // Multiplication of 2x2 matrix, by definition      
    static BigInteger[] multiply(BigInteger[] m1, BigInteger[] m2) {
        return new BigInteger[] {
            m1[0].multiply(m2[0]).add(m1[1].multiply(m2[2])),
            m1[0].multiply(m2[1]).add(m1[1].multiply(m2[3])),
            m1[2].multiply(m2[0]).add(m1[3].multiply(m2[2])),
            m1[2].multiply(m2[1]).add(m1[3].multiply(m2[3]))};
    }

    // Log(n) algorithm to raise 2x2 matrix to n-th power       
    static BigInteger[] power(BigInteger[] m, int n) {
        assert n > 0;
        if(n == 1) {
            return m;
        }
        if(n % 2 == 0) {
            BigInteger[] root = power(m, n/2);
            return multiply(root, root);
        } else {
            return multiply(power(m, n-1), m);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super BigInteger> action) {
        if(cur == fence)
            return false; // traversal finished
        if(state == null) {
            // initialize state: done only once
            if(cur == 0) {
                state = new BigInteger[] {BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE};
            } else {
                BigInteger[] res = power(STARTING_MATRIX, cur);
                state = new BigInteger[] {res[1], res[0]};
            }
        }
        action.accept(state[1]);
        // update state
        if(++cur < fence) {
            BigInteger next = state[0].add(state[1]);
            state[0] = state[1];
            state[1] = next;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<BigInteger> trySplit() {
        if(fence - cur < 2)
            return null;
        int mid = (fence+cur) >>> 1;
        if(mid - cur < 100) {
            // resulting interval is too small:
            // instead of jumping we just store prefix into array
            // and return ArraySpliterator
            BigInteger[] array = new BigInteger[mid-cur];
            for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
                tryAdvance(f -> {});
                array[i] = state[0];
            }
            return Spliterators.spliterator(array, ORDERED | NONNULL | SORTED);
        }
        // Jump to another position
        return new FiboSpliterator(cur, cur = mid);
    }

    @Override
    public long estimateSize() {
        return fence - cur;
    }

    @Override
    public int characteristics() {
        return ORDERED | IMMUTABLE | SIZED| SUBSIZED | NONNULL | SORTED;
    }

    @Override
    public Comparator<? super BigInteger> getComparator() {
        return null; // natural order
    }
}
```

This implementation actually faster in parallel for very big `fence` value (like `100000`). Probably even wiser implementation is also possible which would split unevenly reusing the intermediate results of matrix multiplication.

Comment: Why do you update the state *after* `action.accept` instead of before it (in an `else` clause)? Doing it afterwards implies potentially doing unnecessary work, i.e. when `tryAdvance` is not called again…

Comment: Interesting you used the 2x2 matrix multiplication. I'd used the same logic a year ago with `Arrays.parallelPrefix` to solve the same problem. I'll study your code later and either accept your answer or ask questions, as applicable.

[My old code](https://github.com/abhijitsarkar/java8-impatient/blob/master/src/main/java/name/abhijitsarkar/java/java8impatient/concurrency/PracticeQuestionsCh6.java) - just search for the word 'fibonacci'.

Comment: @tagir-valeev, I'll accept your answer. I made my solution based on your code, with some modifications. I've a question: when do the methods `trySplit` and `tryAdvance` get called in the lifecycle of a `Spliterator`?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar, in general it's not specified, so you should expect that `trySplit` and `tryAdvance` are called in any sequence. However current Stream API implementation never calls `trySplit` after `tryAdvance`: first spliterator splits, then its parts are traversed.

Answer (score 4):

Besides the fact that your code is incomplete, there are at least two errors in your `tryAdvance` method recognizable. First, you are not actually making any advance. You are not modifying any state of your spliterator. Second, you are unconditionally invoking the action’s `accept` method which is not matching the fact that you are returning a conditional value rather than `true`.

The purpose of `tryAdvance` is:

- as the name suggests, try to make an advance, i.e. calculate a next value
- if there is a next value, invoke `action.accept` with that value and return `true`
- otherwise just return `false`

Note further that your `trySplit()` does not look very convincing, I don’t even know where to start. You are better off, inheriting from `AbstractSpliterator` and not implementing a custom `trySplit()`. Your operation doesn’t benefit from parallel execution anyway. A stream constructed with that source could only gain an advantage from parallel execution if you chain it with quiet expensive per-element operations.

Answer (score 4):

In general you don't need implementing the spliterator. If you really need a `Spliterator` object, you may use stream for this purpose:

```
Spliterator.OfLong spliterator = Stream
        .iterate(new long[] { 0, 1 },
                prev -> new long[] { prev[1], prev[0] + prev[1] })
        .mapToLong(pair -> pair[1]).spliterator();
```

Testing:

```
for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
    spliterator.tryAdvance((LongConsumer)System.out::println);
```

Please note that holding Fibonacci numbers in `long` variable is questionable: it overflows after Fibonacci number 92. So if you want to create spliterator which just iterates over first 92 Fibonacci numbers, I'd suggest to use predefined array for this purpose:

```
Spliterator.OfLong spliterator = Spliterators.spliterator(new long[] {
        1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765,
        10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811, 514229, 832040, 1346269, 2178309,
        3524578, 5702887, 9227465, 14930352, 24157817, 39088169, 63245986, 102334155, 165580141,
        267914296, 433494437, 701408733, 1134903170, 1836311903, 2971215073L, 4807526976L,
        7778742049L, 12586269025L, 20365011074L, 32951280099L, 53316291173L, 86267571272L, 139583862445L,
        225851433717L, 365435296162L, 591286729879L, 956722026041L, 1548008755920L, 2504730781961L,
        4052739537881L, 6557470319842L, 10610209857723L, 17167680177565L, 27777890035288L,
        44945570212853L, 72723460248141L, 117669030460994L, 190392490709135L, 308061521170129L,
        498454011879264L, 806515533049393L, 1304969544928657L, 2111485077978050L, 3416454622906707L,
        5527939700884757L, 8944394323791464L, 14472334024676221L, 23416728348467685L, 37889062373143906L,
        61305790721611591L, 99194853094755497L, 160500643816367088L, 259695496911122585L, 420196140727489673L,
        679891637638612258L, 1100087778366101931L, 1779979416004714189L, 2880067194370816120L,
        4660046610375530309L, 7540113804746346429L
}, Spliterator.ORDERED);
```

Array spliterator also splits well, so you will have real parallel processing.