# How to make this fibonacci function faster?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, fibonacci

This function to find the nth fibonacci works.

```
a = 1
b = 2

fibonacci :: Int -> Int
fibonacci 1 = a
fibonacci 2 = b
fibonacci n = (fibonacci (n-1)) + (fibonacci (n-2))
```

But it is slow. If I do `map fibonacci [1..]` it really slows down as the numbers come. I'm guessing this is overhead due to how much stack is being used and the sheer number of calculations - doing each one down to `a` and `b` rather than just adding the last two together.

How can I improve it so it's much faster, but still use a functional programming style? (I'm a definite haskell and FP newbie!)
I tried something in Python that was lightning by comparison.

Tips are as welcome if not more welcome than working code!

Comment: C'mon. Every Haskell programmer should know this page: https://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/haskell/evolution.html

Comment: @EugeneSh. C'mon, "C'mon"?  This comment seems condescending.

Comment: @luqui Isn't it depending on the facial expression?

Comment: I agree it's condescending. Especially coupled with "every" and "should", it says that anyone who doesn't already know this page must not be a real Haskell programmer. But you can't be born knowing everything interesting: OP is one of [today's lucky 10,000](https://xkcd.com/1053/) and it's not nice to imply that he should have known it already.

Comment: Oh man.. given that page I have linked to is *humorous*, and not really educational (well, somewhat), my saying was about the same that saying that "to understand recursion one should understand recursion" - not a very serious saying too. It is known by a term "joke".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that this will result in **dramatic branching**. Say you call `fibonacci 5`, then this will result in the following *call tree*:

```
fibonacci 5
    fibonacci 4
        fibonacci 3
            fibonacci 2
            fibonacci 1
        fibonacci 2
    fibonacci 3
        fibonacci 2
        fibonacci 1
```

As you can see `fibonacci 3` is called twice, `fibonacci 2` is called three times and `fibonacci 1` is called twice (in this very small example). There is a huge amount of overlap: you call the same function with the same arguments multiple times. This is of course inefficient: once you know that `fibonacci 3` is `3`, there is no need to calculate it a second time. Of course in this very small example that's not really an issue: calculating `fibonacci 3` is a matter of nanoseconds. But in case you have to calculate `fibonacci 100` multiple times, this will have a dramatic impact. The number of *redundant* calls also scales exponentially (so this is not some small problem that only has some impact in the margin).

What you can do is work with *accumulator(s)*: variables you pass recursively and update accordingly. For fibonacci, there are two such variables, the *f(n-2)* and *f(n-1)*. You then each time calculate the sum of these two and *shift* so:

```
fibonacci :: Int -> Int
fibonacci 1 = a
fibonacci 2 = b
fibonacci n = fib' (n-2) a b
    fib' 0 x y = x+y
    fib' i x y = fib' (i-1) y (x+y)
```

In this case the call tree will look like:

```
fibonacci 5
    fib' 3 1 2
        fib' 2 2 3
            fib' 1 3 5
                fib' 0 5 8
```

This thus results into five calls (against nine calls for the original code). Of course the number of calls is not a guarantee on performance, since some methods do more work, but our approach scales *linearly* with *n* whereas the original approach scales *exponentially* with *n*. So even if the original method is thousands of times faster, eventually the difference in the number of calls will be that huge, that it will be outperformed.

Comment: thanks for the v clear explanation on why so slow - knew it was something like that, but the branching is really clear

Comment: I get how your solution works - why does `fib'` store the values when mine didn't? Was I expecting too much from GHC?

Comment: @JamesWilson, a lot of Haskell newbies expect GHC to be magic, which I blame on the fanboy press.  GHC is good in that you can abstract a *lot* and not have to pay the abstraction cost, but it's not going to change the asymptotics of the algorithm you use.

Comment: @JamesWilson, the direct answer to your question is that `fib'` stores its intermediate values in its two accumulator parameters.  Your implementation has no mechanism to store them.  You can explicitly memoize, though. https://wiki.haskell.org/Memoization

Comment: @luqui sometimes the full laziness transformation actually does improve asymptotics. Of course, sometimes it makes them worse, too...

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap it up with memoization to eliminate redundant computations

```
fibonacci = (map fibm [0..] !!)
    where fibm 1 = a
          fibm 2 = b
          fibm n = fibonacci (n-1) + fibonacci (n-2)
```

for your given `a` and `b` initial values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use matrix multiplication to calculate fibonacci numbers in O(logN) time. Similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661633/finding-out-nth-fibonacci-number-for-very-large-n).