# Why can't I store all Fibonacci numbers up to the 1000000th in a Python list?

Tags: python-3.x

This code gives out a fibonacci number.
With larger number it produces memory error. Can i allocate more ram or resources to the compiler or is there a more efficient code that i can use?

```
list1 = [0, 1]
x = 0
while x < 1000000:
    list1.append(list1[-1] + list1[-2])
    x+=1
print(list1[-1])
```

Comment: https://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/67989-highest-fibonacci-number-ever-calculated.html

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but you will need a lot of memory for it...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689390/nth-term-for-fibonacci-series-for-enormous-data-inputwithout-recursion-or-loop

Comment: https://web2.0calc.com/questions/1-000-000th-fibonacci-number

Comment: `for x in range(1000000):` is more pythonic

Comment: @Caleth how can you achieve the same using for loops?

Comment: That replaces the `x = 0 while x < 1000000: x+=1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are interested in the last number, don't store the intermediate results.

I just tried it (using `sys.getsizeof()`) and the sum of all integer values in the list would be 46308778320 bytes. Which is 46 GByte.

Even though the 1000000th Fibobacci number only has 92592 bytes

There is no limit to how big an integer can be in Python.

This is how the size of the integers grows:

[image]

A small integer in Python has already has 28 bytes, which is quite large compared to a C int.

More info on this can be found at ["sys.getsizeof(int)" returns an unreasonably large value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365624/sys-getsizeofint-returns-an-unreasonably-large-value)

How to calculate the total size?

```
import sys
fib = None
size_fib = 0

for _ in range(1000000):
    fib = ... # calculation here
    size_fib += sys.getsizeof(fib)

print(size_fib)
```

Comment: thanks, can you suggest a better way of doing this?

Comment: What are you really up to?

Comment: i want to find a particular fibonacci number.

Comment: how can i find the size of all the integers without appending all the integers to the list?

Comment: I just added them up in a loop, like you did with `x`.

Comment: wouldn't that require the same amount of memory though?

Comment: Nope, it's just one variable.

Answer (score 0):

I found the 1000000th Fibobacci number  using the following code,
it took a minute or so to calculate the result.

```
cache = {}
for x in range(1, 1000001):
    if x > 4:
        cache.pop(x-3, x-4)

    if x <= 2:
        value = 1
        cache[x] = value
    else:
        value = cache[x - 1] + cache[x - 2]
        cache[x] = value
print(value)
```