# Calculate nth term of Fibonacci sequence in Python

Tags: python, matrix, fibonacci

The following code is to calculate nth term og fibonacci sequence in python using matrix exponentiation for various test cases t.But the program gives absurd output.Please tell me where i am wrong.when i ran the code in C++ it runs perfectly.

```
class matrix:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=self.b=self.c=1
        self.d=0

    def mul(self,e,f):
        ret = matrix()
        ret.a=(e.a*f.a)+(e.b+f.c)
        ret.b=(e.a*f.b)+(e.b+f.d)
        ret.c=(e.c*f.a)+(e.d+f.c)
        ret.d=(e.c*f.b)+(e.d+f.d)
        return ret

    def exp(self,a,p):
        if(p==0):
            temp=matrix()
            temp.a=temp.b=temp.c=temp.d=1
            return temp
        if(p==1):
            return a
        if(p%2==0):
            return self.exp(self.mul(a,a),p/2)
        else:
            return self.mul(a,self.exp(self.mul(a,a),(p-1)/2))

    def fib(self,n):
        if (n==0):
            return 0
        if (n==1):
            return 1
        s=matrix()
        s=self.exp(s,n)
        return s.d

t=int(raw_input())
while(t>0):
    v=matrix()
    n=int(raw_input())
    print v.fib(n)
    t=t-1
```

Comment: related: [nth fibonacci number in sublinear time](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1525521/4279). Here's an [implementation of algorithm from SICP](https://github.com/zed/txfib/blob/master/fibonacci.py#L139) (ignore the decorator and `yield None`, replace the last `yield` by `return`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues, in order of importance:

1) Your multiplication is wrong. Note the multiplications at the right where you have sums):

```
def mul(self,e,f):
    ret = matrix()
    ret.a=(e.a*f.a)+(e.b*f.c)
    ret.b=(e.a*f.b)+(e.b*f.d)
    ret.c=(e.c*f.a)+(e.d*f.c)
    ret.d=(e.c*f.b)+(e.d*f.d)
    return ret
```

2) In the last line, you do `return s.d` but you should return `s.b` or `s.c` or you will get one less fibonacci.

3) The line `temp.a=temp.b=temp.c=temp.d=1` is not necessary because the constructor does the work. Besides it is wrong, because `d` should be `0`.

4) Why are `mul` and `exp` class functions if they don't use `self`. It does no harm but they should be `@staticmethod`

5) Again, it does no harm but your second recursive call is unnecessarily complex. Just write:

```
    return matrix.mul(a,matrix.exp(a, p-1))
```

Comment: Sir can you suggest where i should use modulo (%) so that it calculates fibonacci for large numbers (>10^7) in very less time

Comment: @KartikKhare: Please, don't call me "sir"... About your question, your modulo operation is well placed, my suggestion was just to change the `else:` part, because it is simpler this way (although equivalent). Anyway if you want to be extra fast you can calculate it in constant time using the __Binet's formula__.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your `__init__` function. In python the so-called variables are just 'tags' to data in the memory. To compare with C/C++, these can be thought of as pointers. when you assign `self.a = self.b = self.c`, you are basically assigning three different names to the same data in the memory. Any change you make in `a` will be reflected back in `b` and `c` and so on.

For your problem where you need three separate variables, one way to change the `__init__` function is like:

```
self.a, self.b, self.c = 1, 1, 1
```

or you can use `copy`. `copy()` tells python to assign a new memory location and then assign the tag on the right hand side to that location. For more read the official documentation on this http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html. You can also read a short walk-through on this in [Python Tutorial: Shallow and Deep-copy](http://www.python-course.eu/deep_copy.php)

Comment: once you have the idea that in python the variable are simply names, you can notice that the following statements:

`self.b = 1`
`self.a = self.b`
will assign two different 'variables' as `self.b` has now been determined by python to be an `int` and while assigning `int` objects a new object is created. Again refer to the python doc ref to understand when a new variable is created and when another name to the same variable is created on assignment.

Comment: You are right in principle, but wrong in this particular case: `int` values are immutable in Python, so `a = b = 1` and  `a, b = 1, 1` won't have any different behavior. A different thing would be with mutable objects: `a = b = []`...

Comment: Thank you sir.But after making the above changes the program is still giving the same output.

Comment: refer to my comment above for clarification. In the first case `self.a = self.b = self.c` the object type has not been determined and hence the name will refer to the same variable as that is the default behavior. in the second case where `self.b = 1` is followed by `self.a = self.b`, the type has been determined and hence `self.a` will be a new variable. 

you can verify this by using the command `id(<object-name>)`

Comment: @KartikKhare there are other instances of that behavior in your code. for example in your `exp()` function you again have an assignment
`temp.a = temp.b = temp.c = 1`.

As I mentioned in the above comment `print id(<object-name>)` to cross check what you are doing.

It may also be worthwhile to run your code in [http://www.pythontutor.com/]. It lets you visualize your code

Comment: thank you sir.Actually after making the above changes there was a slight mistake in logic when i made it correct it ran perfectly..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is required for you to use matrix exponentiation for this problem. Unfortunately, I do not know much about Python classes quite yet. However, the following code does what the question heading wants: to find the n-th Fibonacci number. Below I describe this as F_n. Note the initial conditions for low values of n.

```
def fibN( n ):
"""
fibonacci: int -> int
Returns F_n.
Note: F_1 = 0, F_2 = 1, F_3 = 1, F_4 = 2
"""
n = abs( int( n ))
if n == 0:
    fib = 0
elif n == 1:
    fib = 1
else:
    counter = 2  
    f0 = 0
    f1 = 1
    fib = f0 + f1
    while counter <= n:
        fib = f0 + f1
        f0 = f1
        f1 = fib
        counter += 1
return fib
```