# Generalised Fibonacci

Tags: fibonacci

How to find the nth term of the recurrence in log(n) time.

```
F[n]=F[n-1]+F[n-3]
F[2]=1;
F[3]=2;
F[4]=3;
F[5]=4;
```

I could not create the required matrix to exponentiate.
Sorry if this seems somewhat off-topic.

Thanks but i found the answer. 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891964/generalised-fibonacci/891979#891979

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30595844/java-8-lambda-expressions-for-solving-fibonacci-non-recursive-way/30632678#30632678

Answer (score 0):

The nth fibnonacci number is given by:

```
f(n) = Floor(phi^n / sqrt(5) + 1/2)
```

where

```
phi = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2
```

Assuming that the primitive mathematical operations (+, -, * and /) are O(1) you can use this result to compute the nth Fibonacci number in O(log n) time (O(log n) because of the exponentiation in the formula).

With reference to:
[nth fibonacci number in sublinear time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525521/nth-fibonacci-number-in-sublinear-time)

Comment: I wasn't doing for fibonacci series.. but something similar. thanks anyway. also i dont think your answer always gives accurate results for higher values of n.